# getting error while copying file to remote location using powershell scripts in gitlab runner

Tags: powershell, gitlab

I am setting up a GitLab CI/CD pipeline to copy the war file using PowerShell copy-item function.  I am getting below error in the pipeline.  the user is already an administrator on the gitlab runner computer.

> ```
> [servername] Connecting to remote server name failed with the
> following error message: Access is denied. For more information, see
> the  about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>     + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (servername:String) [], PSRemotingT     ransportException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
> ```

Here is my script in .yml file.

GitLab Runner registered in windows server.

Here is my script in .yml file.

```
envvariable_username - Environment variable configured in gitlab CI/CD settings page
$envvariable_password - Environment variable configured in gitlab CI/CD settings page

- powershell Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer_name -argumentlist $envvariable_username,$envvariable_password -ScriptBlock {
            $password = convertto-securestring -String $envvariable_password -AsPlainText -Force
            $mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $envvariable_username, $password
            New-PSDrive -Name "s" -PSProvider FileSystem -root "\\\\computer_name\\share" -Credential $mycred
            New-PSDrive -Name "z" -PSProvider FileSystem -root "\\\\computer_name\\backup" -Credential $mycred
            Copy-Item -Path "s:\\sample.war" -Destination "z:\\sample.war"
            }
```

expected to copy `.war` file from one server location to another server location

Comment: Welcome to SO.. It is clearly mentioned in the error message that you are getting an access denial. So check permissions for the path in the remote system. Run it with elevated mode and check too

Comment: permissions are intact, user is an admin on the remote computer.  same scripts works file if i run in command prompt with run as admin user.  Do we have any option to set run as administrator in my yml file ?

Comment: You are calling powershell.exe followed by your invoke-command and again you are accessing the network drives. You are landing up in to [DOUBLE HOP Issue](https://4sysops.com/archives/solve-the-powershell-multi-hop-problem-without-using-credssp/). Also, you can still use `-RunAs`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried without powershell.exe but did not work.  getting below errorbash: line 52: Invoke-Command: command not found

Comment: I am running powershell script in gitlab CI pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script, you try to execute a script block on a remote server without specifying credentials. That means that either the server has no restrictions or you assume that both servers belong to the same domain, so kerberos will be utilized.
In my experience, when the second is the case, most people forget to evaluate on who's behalf is the script executing. Keep in mind that a process inherits the user context of the parent process unless otherwise specified.

That would mean that the user running your script doesn't have the necessary access to the remote server. You can always evaluate this by first doing this `$env:USERDOMAIN + "\" + $env:USERNAME`

For example a line in your yaml

```
- powershell $env:USERDOMAIN + "\" + $env:USERNAME
```

So when you debug something from a console that you launched with your user, then you don't have 100% replication of the conditions as you are forgetting the most important aspect of any process, that is the logon user.

Then, if this works, I've noticed that from the remote server you are trying to access another remote location. I notice that you are specifying credentials for this part if please do note that if from within a remote session, you try to access any remote resource, then you need to be aware of some caveats. Please read more about them [here](https://sarafian.github.io/2016/07/05/remoting-caveats.html)and especially the one specific to the double hop.

As a word of advice, best way to troubleshoot scripts that utilize remote execution, is to logon on the server with the same user as with the services that runs your scripts, thus replication the conditions 100%. It is also possible to launch only the console with the credentials of another user.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am getting error while executing the userdoamin variable in yaml file.  Here is the error

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am getting error while executing the userdoamin variable in yaml file.  Resolved my issue, I have moved my PowerShell scripts to a file and executing in my yml file in the runner.  My immediate problem resolved but it is not a clean solution.  build file always reporting success even if there are execution errors in the script file.  Looks like gitlab CI pipeline not having good support in executing powershell scripts.  thanks for your help.     - powershell -File DeployScripts.ps1 $daiusername $devsourcepath

Comment: I've not worked with gitlab ci, but you should that the absolute minimum success/failure communication between processes is the exit code. More advanced scenarios include the error stream, but the exit code is the most dependable. Assuming PowerShell does raise the errors properly, put a try/catch around wrapper in your script and on the error exit with a non zero value.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added try/catch and exit code to return an error for every failure.

Comment: Please feel free to up vote for the correct answer.